# Why does the position of my text change when I make it a link?

Tags: css

I am working on an adapted version of the [flask tutorial](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/examples/tutorial/flaskr/templates/base.html).

Here is the problematic part of my HTML file (simplified) -

```css
nav {
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

nav h1 {
  flex: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

nav h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li,
header .action {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1><a href="index.html">My web app</a></h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Not logged in</li>
    <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is that the `Not logged in` text is positioned higher than the `Log In` link. If I surround the `Not logged in` text with an anchor element, then it becomes horizontally aligned with the `Log In` link.

In the Firefox inspector, both the `Not logged in` text and `Log In` link have identical styles `display: block; padding: 0.5rem; list-style: none; font-family: sans-serif` except that `Log In` link has one additional style `color: #377ba8`. However the `Not logged in` text box model has a border height of 35 (excluding padding), compared to 19 to `Log In` link. Why are they different?

Why is the `Not logged in` text not vertically aligned  with `Log In` link?

Comment: There is a nested padding for the anchor element. Remove it and it will be aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add padding to `nav ul li a`. It was acting like a nested padding and thus the alignment difference.

```css
nav {
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

nav h1 {
  flex: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

nav h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li, /* Removed anchor selector */
header .action {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1><a href="index.html">My web app</a></h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Not logged in</li>
    <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Doe that mean the declaration part of the css rule is applied recursively to each of the comma-separated list of selectors?

Comment: @user2309803 Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1):

```
nav ul li a, nav ul li, header .action {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

`nav ul li a, nav ul li` this applies padding twice to your login

solution

```
nav ul li, header .action {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```